# IWICFormatConverter: Converting from a format that supports transparency

Tags: alphablending, wic, pixelformat

I'm looking for a way to specify a background (matte) color to use when converting from a pixel format with transparency support to one without transparency support using Windows Imaging Components.

This seems like a basic requirement, what am I missing?

Related MSDN topics:

[WIC Pixel formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[IWICFormatConverter.Initialize method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690279%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)